# Cocopad custom project already on trunk downloading properly only on my computer

Tags: swift, cocoapods

there,

I created a custom Cocoa pod named SwiftImageCarousel. I uploaded it on the pod trunk and etc. I tested it and it is working fine with the least code written possible in a Podfile such as :

```
target 'BookStore' do
  use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftImageCarousel', '1.0.1'

end
```

All working perfectly and the project downloading alrgiht, etc.
When I test it on a different computer, however, it does not work like that. Specifying the source as:

```
'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

does not work. It only works with a direct link to the repo, like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/Centroida/SwiftImageCarousel.git'
```

I wonder what could be the issue for that?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Did you try to execute a `pod repo update` before the `pod install` command?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the updates possible, etc

Comment: Actually I just run the `pod repo update` and by running the `pod search SwiftImageCarousel` I could find it. Are you sure you did all the right steps? It works on my computer

Comment: Thank you, my friend, I guess I did not do the steps correctly. I suppose it needed sometime to go online, etc